# Search for holiday doy IN (string) (Postgresql)

Tags: sql, postgresql, postgresql-9.4

This work:

```
WITH month AS ( 
SELECT date_part('doy',d.dt) as doy,
dt::date as date
FROM generate_series('2017-01-01','2017-01-15', interval '1 day') as d(dt)
) 

SELECT date, 
CASE
WHEN doy IN (1,2,3) THEN 0 ELSE 8 END
FROM month
```

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/aed15/10

But if I store 1,2,3 as a string

```
CREATE TABLE holidays
   (id int4,days character(60));       
INSERT INTO holidays
   (id,days)
VALUES
   ('2017','1,2,3');
```

...and replace 1,2,3 with this string:

```
WITH month AS ( 
SELECT date_part('doy',d.dt) as doy, 
dt::date as date
FROM generate_series('2017-01-01','2017-01-15', interval '1 day') as d(dt)
) 

SELECT date, days,
CASE
WHEN doy::text IN (days) THEN 0 ELSE 8 END
FROM month
LEFT JOIN holidays ON id=2017
```

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/aed15/13

It seems that 'days' is not casted correct. But I cannot figure out how.

TIA,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the shortest solution here would be turning string list to array and using `ANY` construct:

```
WITH month AS ( 
SELECT date_part('doy',d.dt) as doy,
dt::date as date
FROM generate_series('2017-01-01','2017-01-15', interval '1 day') as d(dt)
) 

SELECT date, days,
CASE
WHEN doy::text = ANY(concat('{',days,'}')::text[]) THEN 0 ELSE 8 END
FROM month
LEFT JOIN holidays ON id=2017
```

But I would rethink the whole solution, as it feels wrong

Comment: I have to store the holidays separate. What is your suggestion?

Comment: I would probably have holiday table with concrete dates. a hundred years of hilidays would be still small exception table to jaoin against

Comment: WHEN doy = ANY (string_to_array(days,',')::integer[]) THEN 0 ELSE 8 seems also to work. Any other suggestions?

Comment: sure. I think cast string to array is faster then parsing string to array, but yeah - should work as well.main idea of my answer is that using `= ANY(array)` construct is mucheasier here then making scalar of of string. surely you can use different ways to make string an array